# ElasticSearch - transllog is already closed

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Since some days, i got several crash in my applog when i'm trying to add some documents
Everething worked fine before...

trace:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: RemoteTransportException[[server][1.1.1.1:9300][indices:data/write/index]]; nested: IndexFailedEngineException[Index failed for [com.domain.util.SearchField#2257100]]; nested: AlreadyClosedException[translog is already closed];
```

all trace:

```html
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: RemoteTransportException[[server][1.1.1.1:9300][indices:data/write/index]]; nested: IndexFailedEngineException[Index failed for [com.domain.util.SearchField#2257100]]; nested: AlreadyClosedException[translog is already closed];
 at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.getValue(BaseFuture.java:290)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.get(BaseFuture.java:277)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture.get(BaseFuture.java:116)
 at com.utils.ElasticsearchHelper.add(ElasticsearchHelper.java:230)
 at com.dao.searchable.impl.DaoSearchable.merge(DaoSearchable.java:478)
 at com.dao.searchable.impl.DaoSearchable.merge(DaoSearchable.java:31)
 at com.dao.util.impl.DaoEventImpl.listenObject(DaoEventImpl.java:417)
 at com.dao.util.impl.DaoEventImpl.addSearchEvent(DaoEventImpl.java:193)
 at com.utils.ShapesDaoUtils.manageEvent(ShapesDaoUtils.java:82)
 at com.dao.impl.ShapesDaoBaseJpa.merge(ShapesDaoBaseJpa.java:230)
 at com.services.collectiondocument.impl.CollectionDocumentsServiceImpl.addTagToCollectionDocuments(CollectionDocumentsServiceImpl.java:691)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1174.addTagToCollectionDocuments(Unknown Source)
 at com.services.impl.SampleServiceImpl.generateTechPacks(SampleServiceImpl.java:1480)
 at com.services.impl.SampleServiceImpl.generateTechPacksById(SampleServiceImpl.java:1352)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1291.generateTechPacksById(Unknown Source)
 at com.controller.sample.SampleController.generateTechPacks(SampleController.java:210)
 at com.controller.sample.SampleController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$df54e710.invoke(<generated>)
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
 at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:55)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
 at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
 at com.controller.sample.SampleController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$cccf0aef.generateTechPacks(<generated>)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
 at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
 at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
 at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
 at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
 at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter.doFilter(MetadataDisplayFilter.java:75)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.doFilter(SAMLEntryPoint.java:99)
 at com.oxit.fwk.security.fallback.OxitFallbackEntryPoint.doFilter(OxitFallbackEntryPoint.java:71)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:158)
 at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:104)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:172)
 at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:95)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at com.oxit.fwk.loginaudit.filter.LoginAuditFilter.doFilter(LoginAuditFilter.java:75)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:70)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
 at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:188)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2516)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2505)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: RemoteTransportException[[server][1.1.1.1:9300][indices:data/write/index]]; nested: IndexFailedEngineException[Index failed for [com.domain.util.SearchField#2257100]]; nested: AlreadyClosedException[translog is already closed];
Caused by: [pace][[pace][2]] IndexFailedEngineException[Index failed for [com.domain.util.SearchField#2257100]]; nested: AlreadyClosedException[translog is already closed];
 at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.index(InternalEngine.java:473)
 at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.index(IndexShard.java:571)
 at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.Engine$Index.execute(Engine.java:836)
 at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportReplicationAction.java:1073)
 at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:170)
 at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase.performOnPrimary(TransportReplicationAction.java:579)
 at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase$1.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:452)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: translog is already closed
 at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog.ensureOpen(Translog.java:1845)
 at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog.add(Translog.java:513)
 at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.innerIndex(InternalEngine.java:553)
 at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.index(InternalEngine.java:468)
 ... 10 more
```

I don't understandwhy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the index, a lot of documents and _bulk requests are executed so long. And the error occurs when the [translog](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-translog.html) is in the recording process.

> Changes to Lucene are only persisted to disk during a Lucene commit,
>   which is a relatively heavy operation and so cannot be performed after
>   every index or delete operation. Changes that happen after one commit
>   and before another will be lost in the event of process exit or HW
>   failure.

I helped change **index.translog.sync_interval: 10s** in elasticsearch.yml
and change number of documents (500-1000) in a [Bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-bulk.html) request.

Elasticsearch needs tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Reindexing sometimes causes the same problem for me. The index gets stuck, and writes to documents in it fail with "translog is already closed". When this happens, closing and re-opening the index (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/indices-close.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/indices-open-close.html ) makes it usable again.